# integrating google map api in angular 2

Tags: google-maps, angular

I am trying to use google map API to find hospitals in certain location using this library : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places.

I succeded to make the request and display result in console but i want to put the result in variable to display it using the ngFor in the html page and that is where i found this problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeNgg.png)

Here is my code:

```
hospSearch_res:any[] = [];
searchHospitals(){
console.log('Search works');
console.log(this.hosp_lat);
console.log(this.hosp_lng);
console.log(this.hosp_rad);

var search_loc = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat,this.lng);

var request = {
  location: search_loc,
  radius: '1000',
  types: ['hospital']
};

var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById('test'));
service.nearbySearch(request, this.callback);

}

callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    // this.hospSearch_res = results;
    //let res = JSON.stringify(results);
    console.log(results);
    this.hospSearch_res = results;
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      //this.hospSearch_res.push(place);
      /*console.log(results[i]);
      console.log(results[i].name);*/

    }

  }
}
```

This is my first project with angular 2 and i got stcuk for this problem, any help would be much appreciated .
Thank you

Comment: It says this is undefined..

Comment: Yes that was the error. Karbos reponse solved te problem, thank you anyway

Comment: Hi, I am new to angular 2. can you please help, how to make service in angular2 for google maps API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your callback function by an arrow function to bind `this` :

```
var service = new 
google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById('test'));
service.nearbySearch(request, this.callback);

}

callback = (results, status) => { //Arrow Function Here !
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Apparently i still have a lot to learn in angular 2.